# Origem da expressão «ficar a matar» ― o que é que mata o quê?

Tags: etimologia, expressões-idiomáticas

O [Priberam define ***a matar:***](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/matar)

> Ficar muito bem, otimamente (ex.: *essa roupa fica-lhe a matar*).

O que eu gostaria  de saber é, no mínimo, qual é a primeira ocorrência conhecida desta expressão. E se possível, donde é que ela vem ― tem mesmo que ver com matar, de tirar a vida? O que é que mata o quê?

Avanço já com o que apurei. Na minha memória *a matar* neste sentido está sempre associado ao verbo *ficar*, mas a [Infopédia](http://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/matar) admite também *estar a matar*, e o [Aulete digital](http://www.aulete.com.br/matar) apresenta o exemplo *este seu comentário soou-me a matar*.

Aqui em Setúbal já ouvi uma expressão possivelmente relacionada, do tipo «a morte do carapau é assado com molho à espanhola», que é como quem diz, «o carapau fica mesmo bem (a matar) é assado com molho à espanhola».

E a expressão já era usada pelo menos à época do Machado de Assis [(«As Bodas de Luís Duarte», *Histórias da Meia-Noite*, 1873):](http://www.dominiopublico.gov.br/download/texto/bv000187.pdf)

> Não era ele bonito de feições no sentido afeminado que alguns dão à beleza masculina; mas não deixava de ter certa correção nas linhas do rosto, o qual se cobria de um véu de serenidade que lhe ficava a matar.

Comment: Já vi o Figo matar a bola no peito e chutar a gol,  já matei minha sede e a fome, nunca matei aula mas já matei vinte e oito pargos numa pescaria, em certas épocas fui obrigado a matar um leão por dia, matei diversas charadas, mas confesso que nunca havia ouvido "matar" usado dessa forma. Mas consta nos dicionários.

Comment: Em Portugal é uma expressão muito comum, @Centaurus , o «ficar a matar». Por exemplo na música Budapeste, dos Mão Morta: «[Mulheres lindas de morrer / Mini-saias a matar](http://www.mao-morta.org/letras04.htm)»

Comment: @Centaurus, «matar um leão por dia» é metafórico ou idiomático? Ou é literal? Não percebo o que significa.

Comment: @ANeves  É idiomático, e metafórico também, é claro.  Tive que lutar muito, batalhar muito, todo dia eu tinha um problema difícil para solucionar, ou um trabalho árduo pra fazer, ou arranjar dinheiro para pagar as contas.  Eu tinha que matar um leão por dia.  Eu solucionava os meus problemas de um dia, sabendo que nos dias seguintes eu teria que batalhar da mesma forma.  Acredito ser uma expressão idiomática relativamente recente pois não me lembro de ouví-la há 30 ou 40 anos.

Comment: No Brasil, se diz [x] é de matar. Quando o cara ver a mulher vestida assim, sente que ela tem vontade de matá-lo. Quer dizer o que o outro "me faz" me mata: https://www.kboing.com.br/odair-jose/e-de-matar/  olhar ou aspecto da pessoa "me mata". :) Por isso é de matar. :) Acho que o " a matar" funciona mais ou menos da mesma forma.

Comment: @Jacinto dou-te um voto para cima, por incluíres a referência a Machado de Assis. Sempre ouvi esta expressão em Portugal com os verbos verbos auxiliares "ficar" e "estar", nisto também tens razão.

Comment: @bad_coder, o Machado de Assis é um dos meus autores favoritos, e aquela citação ficou... a matar.

Answer (score 1):

*Ficar a matar:*  algo ou alguém que é tão bom ou faz tão bem, que por ironia, mata (já que a morte é algo indesejado para a maioria); eis a ironia, para expressar intensidade da opinião em questão.

Exemplo: o vestido é lindo, fica a matar em ti. — O vestido é tão lindo que eu “morro” de admiração por Ella vestida com tal vestido.

Comment: Ronaldo, bem-vindo à comunidade. Essa tua ideia é uma conjetura interessante, mas é apenas uma conjetura tua, certo? Nós aqui queremos respostas fundamentadas. Foi por isso que eu pedi "no mínimo, a primeira ocorrência conhecida desta expressão", porque isso pode ser fundamentado. Já a ideia que esteve por trás da expressão, podemos nunca a conseguir descobrir.

Comment: "Ella" é um nome de mulher, ou é o pronome *ela* com maiúscula e dois eles por engano? Ainda tive para mudar para *ela*, mas fiquei na dúvida (podes clicar em "edit" e mudar à tua vontade).